# My App icon is greyed out on iPad Dock recent icons

Tags: xcode, ipad

On iOS 11 the icon on the dock is grayed out and not clickable after the install when I first open it. If I delete the icon from recent on iPad dock and open the app again the icon appears to be fine.

The icon is fine on home screen but grayed out on the recent dock? 
It happens when every time no matter the source of installation, Xcode, app store or test-flight

Rebooting the device (either between uninstall and reinstall, or while the icon is gray) fixes the icon

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes iOS 11 iPad recent apps dock icon to be grayed out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46740204/what-causes-ios-11-ipad-recent-apps-dock-icon-to-be-grayed-out)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the exact same issue. Here is my StackOverflow post's answer: [What causes iOS 11 iPad recent apps dock icon to be grayed out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46740204/what-causes-ios-11-ipad-recent-apps-dock-icon-to-be-grayed-out/47737460#47737460)

I feel that this is an iOS 11 bug, as I was able to replicate the behavior with the Google Play Music app.

I have also experienced some other weird glitches related to the "Recent apps" section of the dock on iOS 11 on iPad. Sometimes the hand-off safari icon will be positioned half outside of the dock. Another time an app icon was greyed out and still present after I had deleted the app, I was able to grab the icon and drop it on my home screen (only a reboot removed the icon as long pressing on the icon made it jiggle, but no "X" appeared).

Here is the screenshot that I have posted in my answer showing that Google Play Music's app had the same issue.

[image: iPad screenshot]

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18708801)

Comment: @AhmadF I feel that my answer does answer OP's question. It is the exact same issue that I have experienced and from my extensive testing and researching this appears to be nothing more than an iOS 11 bug. Which is what I state in my answer. I also provide evidence that points to my conclusion. Please elaborate how my answer does not answer OP's question.